# How to handle errors using batch commands?

Tags: batch-file, command-line, jenkins, cmd, windows-console

I am trying to delete files that are older than 14 days using this command: `forfiles /P "Path\To\Files" /S /M *.txt /D -14 /C "cmd /c del @path"`

This is the error I get when trying to delete files : `ERROR: No files found with the specified search criteria.`

Is there a way to handle this error or suppress it? The reason being because I am using this command on jenkins and the build fails because of this command. Thanks.

I also looked at ERRORLEVEL and use the following code but it still gave me the error:

```
forfiles /P "Path\To\Files" /S /M *.txt /D -14 /C "cmd /c del @path" | find "ERROR" >nul2>nul
if not ERRORLEVEL 1 (
echo. Uh oh, something bad happened
exit /b 1
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a goto label to check for errors. Simply place `call:checkerrors` after any line that needs errors to be checked.

```
forfiles /P "Path\To\Files" /S /M *.txt /D -14 /C "cmd /c del @path"
call:checkerrors

goto :eof

:checkerrors
if %errorlevel% neq 0 (
    echo. Uh oh, something bad happened
    exit /b 0
)

goto :eof
```

Comment: since you don't do anything with the error, except printing some text on the screen, you can just put the `exit /b 0` after your forfiles line. Jenkins uses the errorcode from the batch script. By default, the errorlevel from the batch script is the error level of the last command in the batch script. `exit` can be used to set the errorlevel to a specific value.

Answer (score 0):

you can sort this error out, keeping all other `ERROR` messages:

```
forfiles /P "Path\To\Files" /S /M *.txt /D -14 /C "cmd /c del @path" 2>&1|find /v "ERROR: No files found with the specified search criteria." | find "ERROR" >nul2>nul
```

**EDIT** only STDOUT was piped to `find`, so the errormessage kept on screen. Edited to write STDERR also to STDOUT, so that `find`can process it.

Comment: Thanks for the response but this answer is still giving me this error: `ERROR: No files found with the specified search criteria.`

Answer (score 0):

if ERROREVEL different from 0, the build is considered as a failure.

```
forfiles /P "Path\To\Files" /S /M *.txt /D -14 /C "cmd /c del @path" | find "ERROR" >nul2>nul
if not ERRORLEVEL 0 (
echo. Uh oh, something bad happened
exit /b 0
)
```

This is also the issue for tools like Gnatcheck  or other that systematically return an ERRORLEVEL diferent from 0 where Jenkins is waiting 0 to continue without mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

Here's some ways I've found to do just what you're asking as I ran into the same issue myself--posted a few times in other places. I'm finding that other solutions might get rid of the actual error text but are ignoring the %ERRORLEVEL% which signals a fail in my application. AND I legitimately want %ERRORLEVEL% just as long as it isn't the "No files found" error.

**Some Examples:**

**Debugging and eliminating the error specifically:**

```
forfiles /p "[file path...]\IDOC_ARCHIVE" /s /m *.txt /d -1 /c "cmd /c del @path" 2>&1 |  findstr /V /O /C:"ERROR: No files found with the specified search criteria."2>&1 | findstr ERROR&&ECHO found error||echo found success
```

**Using a oneliner to return ERRORLEVEL success or failure:**

```
forfiles /p "[file path...]\IDOC_ARCHIVE" /s /m *.txt /d -1 /c "cmd /c del @path" 2>&1 |  findstr /V /O /C:"ERROR: No files found with the specified search criteria."2>&1 | findstr ERROR&&EXIT /B 1||EXIT /B 0
```

**For a SQL Server Agent CmdExec job step I landed on the following. I don't know if it's a bug, but the CmdExec within the step only recognizes the first line of code. Also, CmdExec didn't like 2>&1 to redirect stderr so I encapsulated everything with cmd /c.:**

```
cmd /e:on /c "forfiles /p "C:\SQLADMIN\MAINTREPORTS\SQL2" /s /m *.txt /d -1 /c "cmd /c del @path" 2>&1 |  findstr /V /O /C:"ERROR: No files found with the specified search criteria."2>&1 | findstr ERROR&&EXIT 1||EXIT 0"&exit %errorlevel%
```